# Start a gaussian job from python and wait until .log is done (multiple runs)

Tags: python, linux, gaussian

How can I start a gaussian job from python? I try using subprocess but I don't understand it's working. I have a program which read a file make a gaussian.com file and after this I must sent this to Gaussian to get the gaussian.log, and with this gaussian.log, I modify the first gaussian.com in order to get a new gaussian.log. This procees is done until my energy is lower than a value(this value is read from the gaussian.log). Until the gaussian.log is created the python program must wait the gaussian to finish the log file to extract the data. So I must send a job to gaussian and wait until log file is created. I need this in linux.

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Especially the section about providing an MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without this, it is impossible for people to help you.

Comment: I assume you mean this http://www.arc.ox.ac.uk/content/running-gaussian. The gaussian tag here is for the bell curve function. you need to add a small script to show what you are trying.

Answer (score 0):

```
text = open("input.txt","r")
def Readfromtext()
   read and create gaussian.com
def Write()
   write output
def ModifyCoordinates()
   get new gaussian.com

Readfromtext()
while E<0
   Write()
   "Send gaussian.com to g09 and wait until gaussian.log is created"
   ModifyCoordinates()
```

Comment: And i don't know how to send the job to g09 program from python. I read that this can be done with popen or subprocess( subprocess.call("exit 1", shell=True) ), but I don't know how to implement the code. Gaussian is a general purpose computational chemistry software.